# C Program crashes when calling Opendir after printf

Tags: c, crash, printf, opendir

I am writing a program to list the files within a folder.
In the code below, it runs fine but if I un-comment

```
//printf("This makes the program crash.\n");
```

and run it again the program crashes. It will not print out "folder opened" so it is crashing on the opendir. It will also crash if I define 'd' inside the getfiles function instead of passing it in.  I am compiling with MinGW.  My program is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

    void getfiles(DIR *d) {
        //DIR* d;
        struct dirent *dir;
        char* folder_dest;
        printf("Please enter name of upload folder.\n");
        scanf("%s", folder_dest);
        d = opendir(folder_dest);
        printf("folder opened\n");  //does not print when it crashes

        if (d) {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
                if( dir->d_type != DT_DIR) {
                    printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                }
            }
            closedir(d);
        }
    }

    int main(void) {
        DIR *d;
        //printf("This makes the program crash.\n");
        getfiles(d);
        return(0);
    }
```

Comment: The first thing to do is echo your input.  You should check the return value from `scanf()` -- if it is not 1, you should not use the value at all.  Then you should print the string your program actually got: `printf("Got: <<%s>>\n", folder_dest);` -- then you can see what it is working on, rather than guessing.  But you've not allocated space as [ouah](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah) diagonsed, and that's the primary cause of your trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* folder_dest;
scanf("%s", folder_dest)
```

`folder_dest` is not initialized in your program and points at a random memory address. `scanf` will then invoked undefined behavior when writing characters. Use an character array instead of a `char` pointer. A better solution would be to use `fgets` plus `sscanf` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Why would that only cause the program to crash if I include the printf in the main?

Comment: @Galarodo: that's the beauty of undefined behaviour.  It can manifest itself in many different ways.  It probably just so happens that you trample memory in the wrong place such that the crash occurs.  But from any time from when you invoked undefined behaviour (by passing an uninitialized pointer to `scanf()`) onwards, the program crash in any bizarre way it chooses, and the problem is still the `scanf()` call.